# Sorting with a python dictionary

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I have a dictionary of "documents" in python with document ID numbers as keys and dictionaries (again) as values. These internal dictionaries each have a 'weight' key that holds a floating-point value of interest. In other words:

`documents[some_id]['weight'] = ...`

What I want to do is obtain a list of my document IDs sorted in descending order of the 'weight' value. I know that dictionaries are inherently unordered (and there seem to be a lot of ways to do things in Python), so what is the most painless way to go? It feels like kind of a messy situation...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would convert the dictionary to a list of tuples and sort it based on weight (in reverse order for descending), then just remove the objects to get a list of the keys

```
l = documents.items()
l.sort(key=lambda x: x[1]['weight'], reverse=True)
result = [d[0] for d in l]
```

Comment: What does the [1] in x[1]['weight'] represent? Is the lambda expression giving a sort of prototype dictionary structure that differs only in the 'weight' value (ignoring ID?); thus, python figures out that it needs to use the weights to sort?

Comment: Dictionary's items generates a list of 2-element tuples. The first item is the key, the 2nd item is the value. By saying [1] I'm only looking at the value and then looking at the weight property. Setting the sorting key to this lambda will make python pass each element to this lambda, evaluate the lambda and then use the value to sort the elements. See key functions here https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting/

Answer (score 2):

I took the approach that you might want the keys as well as the rest of the object:

```
# Build a random dictionary
from random import randint
ds = {}                             # A |D|ata |S|tructure
for i in range(20,1,-1):
  ds[i]={'weight':randint(0,100)}

sortedDS = sorted(ds.keys(),key=lambda x:ds[x]['weight'])
for i in sortedDS :
 print i,ds[i]['weight']
```

`sorted()` is a python built in that takes a list and returns it sorted (obviously), however it can take a `key` value that it uses to determine the rank of each object. In the above case it uses the `'weight'` value as the key to sort on.

The advantage of this over Ameers answer is that it returns the order of *keys* rather than the items. Its an extra step, but it means you can refer back into the original data structure

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for me.  The inspiration for it came from [OrderedDict](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html?highlight=ordereddict#ordereddict-examples-and-recipes) and [question #9001509](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9001509/python-dictionary-sort-by-key)

```
from collections import OrderedDict

d = {
    14: {'weight': 90},
    12: {'weight': 100},
    13: {'weight': 101},
    15: {'weight': 5}
 }

sorted_dict = OrderedDict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda rec: rec[1].get('weight')))
print sorted_dict
```